# Where does the baDabanala tantra recognize vajravarahi as a Buddhist diety originally?

Tags: tantra, goddess, buddhism, shaktism

From the article ["VajravArAhI"](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1143&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) at the Kamakotimandali website:

> *BhagavatI bimbAmbikA recognizes the fact that the deity is Buddhist in origin, as does baDabAnala tantra*, and both prescribe the use of trishakti-chAmuNDA during the observance of tAntrikI sandhyA during mahAnishA instead of vajravArAhI, however prescribing her mantra for purposes of Japa

So the question is - Where does the baDabanala tantra recognize vajravarahi as a Buddhist diety originally?

Comment: I don't understand why there are close votes. Given that you are asking for the verses of a Tantra that recognize the concerned deity as of Buddhist origin.